# Pandoc builder system

Tags: makefile, make

I have created a GNUMake [building system for pandoc](https://github.com/lf-araujo/mighty_make). It has grown quite a bit, I wonder if I can optimize it further. Would it be possible, for instance, that it only runs a target if the output hasn't changed since last run?

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := pdf

INPUTDIR=$(CURDIR)/source
OUTPUTDIR=$(CURDIR)/output
STYLEDIR=$(CURDIR)/style
NAME = $(notdir $(shell basename "$(CURDIR)"))

FILFILES = $(wildcard style/*.py)

FILTER := $(foreach FILFILES, $(FILFILES), --filter $(FILFILES))
TEXFLAGS = --filter pandoc-crossref --filter pandoc-citeproc $(FILTER) --latex-engine=xelatex

ifeq ($(shell test -e "$(STYLEDIR)/template.tex" && echo -n yes),yes)
    TEXTEMPLATE = "--template=$(STYLEDIR)/template.tex"
endif

ifeq ($(shell test -e "$(STYLEDIR)/reference.docx" && echo -n yes),yes)
    DOCXTEMPLATE = "--reference-docx=$(STYLEDIR)/reference.docx"
endif

help:

    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'Makefile for automated typography using pandoc.                         '
    @echo 'Version 1.0                        '
    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'Usage:                                                                 '
    @echo '   make prepare    first time use, setting the directories     '
    @echo '   make html       generate a web version             '
    @echo '   make pdf        generate a PDF file             '
    @echo '   make docx       generate a Docx file            '
    @echo '   make tex        generate a Latex file               '
    @echo '   make beamer     generate a beamer presentation              '
    @echo '   make all        generate all files                 '
    @echo '   make update     update the makefile to last version       '
    @echo '   make            will fallback to PDF               '
    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'It implies some directories in the filesystem: source, output and style'
    @echo 'It also implies that the bibliography will be defined via the yaml     '
    @echo '                                                                       '
    @echo 'Depends on pandoc-citeproc and pandoc-crossref                         '
    @echo 'Get local templates with: pandoc -D latex/html/etc                     '
    @echo '                                                                       '



all : tex docx html epub pdf


pdf:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)/"*.md \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).pdf" \
    $(TEXTEMPLATE) \
    $(TEXFLAGS) 2>pandoc.log
    xdg-open "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).pdf"

tex:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)"/*.md \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --filter pandoc-citeproc \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).tex" \
    --latex-engine=xelatex

docx:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)"/*.md \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --filter pandoc-citeproc \
    $(DOCXTEMPLATE) \
    --toc \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).docx"

html:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)"/*.md \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).html" \
    --include-in-header="$(STYLEDIR)/style.css" \
    -t html5 \
    --toc \
    --standalone \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --filter pandoc-citeproc \
    --number-sections
    rm -rf "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source"
    mkdir "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source"
    cp -r "$(INPUTDIR)/figures" "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source/figures"

epub:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)"/*.md \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).epub" \
    --toc \
    --standalone \
    --filter pandoc-crossref \
    --filter pandoc-citeproc
    rm -rf "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source"
    mkdir "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source"
    cp -r "$(INPUTDIR)/figures" "$(OUTPUTDIR)/source/figures"

beamer:
    pandoc "$(INPUTDIR)/"*.md \
    -t beamer \
    -o "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).pdf" \
    $(TEXTEMPLATE) \
    $(TEXFLAGS) 2>pandoc.log
    xdg-open "$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(NAME).pdf"

prepare:
    mkdir "output"
    mkdir "source"
    mkdir "style"

update:
    wget http://tiny.cc/mighty_make -O Makefile

clean:
    rm -f "$(OUTPUTDIR)/" *.md *.html *.pdf *.tex *.docx

.PHONY: help pdf docx html tex clean
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only runs a target if the output hasn't changed since last run

Consider writing rules like this:

```
%.pdf: %.md
        pandoc -o $@ $<
```

For that to work, the current `all: ... pdf` would need to mention particular *.pdf files, perhaps by globbing: `$(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,*.md)`

Comment: The problem is that pandoc will generate one pdf from several md files, I can't figure out how to handle this in the syntax you suggest...

Comment: I frequently write `Makefile`s that start with `all: foo.pdf bar.pdf baz.pdf`, followed by the generic %.pdf rule I mentioned above. So that would be three invocations of pandoc in my example. If you're not willing to list particular targets after "all", I was thinking you could get patsubst globbing to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion really helped and the makefile now recognizes the files that changed. I made an example of it in use [here](https://lf-araujo.github.io/2017/08/13/letter-again.html).